# Replace character in string and form all possible combination

Tags: python

I am doing text recognition with pytesseract. Sometimes text is not properly extracted.
For example, "DDR4" might be interpreted as "ODR4"

Hence I have a dictionary which record all possible escape, and code to detect how many char needed to be replace and its index for example,

```
my_dictionary= {
            'D': ['O', '0'],
            'O': 'D',
            '0': 'D'
}

user_input = "DDR4"
char_to_replace = 0
char_index = []
for index, val in enumerate(user_input):
    if val in my_dictionary:
        char_to_replace += 1
        char_index.append(index)
```

In this case, how could I produce a list of all possible combination, for example

> D0R4, DOR4, 00R4, 0OR4, OOR4, O0R4, 0DR4, ODR4

Appreciate for any inputs

Comment: `more_itertools` has some functions for that, for example https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations

Comment: You can check for the indices where your character appears: for example here you would have 2 indices. Hence you get every 2 combination of your 3 characters (with itertools.permutation (O,D,0) and insert it in your original string at the indices you retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have come up with, pretty ugly code and im sure it can be done much easier with itertools, but what the heck - i hope it helps:

```
my_dictionary = {
            'D': ['O', '0'],
            'O': 'D',
            '0': 'D'
}

user_input = "DDR4"


def replace_char(variable=None, replace_index=None, replace_with=None):
    """Supplementary function"""
    return variable[:replace_index] + replace_with + variable[replace_index+1:]


# create maximum required iterations (max len of list in dict)
number_of_iterations_required = max([len(f) for f in my_dictionary.values()])

# list for preliminary word combinations
baseword_combinations = [user_input]
for key, val in my_dictionary.items():
    for idx, char in enumerate(user_input):
        if char == key:
            for v in val:
                baseword_combinations.append(replace_char(variable=user_input, replace_index=idx, replace_with=v))

# list for final returns, again append initial input
possible_combinations = [user_input]

for word in baseword_combinations:
    for idx, char in enumerate(word):
        for key, val in my_dictionary.items():
            for v in val:
                if char == key:
                    possible_combinations.append(replace_char(variable=word, replace_index=idx, replace_with=v))
                if char == val:
                    possible_combinations.append(replace_char(variable=word, replace_index=idx, replace_with=key))
        
# get rid of duplicates, print result
print(list(set(possible_combinations)))
```

Result:

```
['OOR4', '00R4', 'ODR4', 'D0R4', '0DR4', 'DDR4', '0OR4', 'O0R4', 'DOR4']
```

---

## Edit

The part with the number_of_iterations_required was unused in my above code, also i reworked it a little to use list comprehension - which makes it much less understandable, but much shorter, so here you go:

```
my_dictionary = {
    'D': ['O', '0'],
    'O': 'D',
    '0': 'D'
}

user_input = "DDR4"


def replace_char(variable=None, replace_index=None, replace_with=None):
    """Supplementary function"""
    return variable[:replace_index] + replace_with + variable[replace_index+1:]


# list for preliminary word combinations
base = [user_input]
base.extend([replace_char(user_input, idx, v) for key, val in my_dictionary.items()
             for idx, char in enumerate(user_input) for v in val if char == key])

# list for final results
final_results = [user_input]
final_results.extend([replace_char(word, idx, key) for word in base for idx, char in enumerate(word)
                      for key, val in my_dictionary.items() for v in val if char == val])

result = list(set(final_results))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm try to solve this problem in this way,hope that can help you:

```
import itertools as it
my_list= ['D','O','0']

result = []
input = 'DDR4'

# 'DDR4' -> '**R4'
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if input[i] in my_list:
        input = input.replace(input[i],'*')


for e in it.product('DO0',repeat=input.count('*')):
    a = list(e)
    input_copy = input
    for i in a:
        # print(i)
        input_copy = input_copy.replace('*',i,1)
    result.append(input_copy)
```

result:

```
['DDR4', 'DOR4', 'D0R4', 'ODR4', 'OOR4', 'O0R4', '0DR4', '0OR4', '00R4']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).